# approximate line segments from array of unsorted points

Tags: algorithm, sorting, image-processing, matrix

[image: Sample Scenario]

The polygon above is actually a collection of a lot of black points closely packed together. I want to approximate these black points as straight line segments. The black points are **not sorted** in any order.

What I'm doing right now is sort these points by selecting any random black point and recursively finding the next closest point until no more points are left, the problem with this method is it might produce inaccurate results, if there is a small gap of points somewhere on the shape or dense lump of points somewhere on the shape. After sorting the points by this algorithm I run [Douglas–Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) to obtain the line segments. Am I doing it right? How can I approach this problem better?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to figure out the point density from the given figure.

A possible approach, which should be robust, is to obtain the minimum spanning tree of the points (using the Euclidean distance). Then prune the short branches and close to form a polygon.

Then Douglas-Peucker is indeed appropriate to simplify the polygon. After you found the longest edges, you can fit lines on them and intersect to obtain sharp corners.